# Gnome-Do - shouldn't it be more stable?

Tags: bug-reporting, gnome-do

Gnome-Do just drove my CPU to 100% for over a minute for no apparent reason. Had to kill the process to stop the fans from blowing themselves apart.

I had other problems with Gnome-Do - sometimes it doesn't recognize any command. I have to restart it so that it can become of any use. I really like the idea and vast array of plugins, but shouldn't it be more reliable? Are there any alternatives to this software?

Another thing - I have never reported a bug. What should I read so that my report is useful to the developers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably this already existing bug report - chime in there..
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-do/+bug/626308

A good alternative would be Synapse - http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/synapse-gnome-do-launcher-app-review-ubuntu/
I'm not sure, though, how relevant all these launchers will be after one starts using unity - I think there's much duplicated functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Think that the first of your bugs is fixed in Do 0.8.4 and later, available in Ubuntu 11.04 - chances are it was either [bug #395190](https://bugs.launchpad.net/do/+bug/395190) or [bug #450852](https://bugs.launchpad.net/do/+bug/450852).

The second one is [bug #589649](https://bugs.launchpad.net/do/+bug/589649) - which was introduced by the fix for the first bug.  It's caused when a broken plugin blocks the Universe updater thread, so there are no Items for Do to return.  This'll be fixed in the next version of Do; I'm not entirely sure as yet what approach I'll take there, though.